# How to place a hole at an angle in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad

I am trying to create my own package in Eagle 6.6. I have to place holes at specific angle of 36 degrees.

I need to place 10 holes on the circle with an angle of 36 degree to each hole.

The package I am trying to create as shown below:

[image: Original package dimensions]

I have created a circle with 5 mm diameter. The first hole I placed at position (0 2.5) so its top and bottom hole also like (0 -2.5). I am confused about how to place next hole at an angle of 36 degrees. I had placed 10 holes on the circle but those are not at correct angle to each other.

The package I am creating as shown below:

[image: my package]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Not sure how you do this in Eagle itself but if you got stuck you could probably make a spreadsheet using the parametric equation for a circle and manually type in all the points.

Comment: That's exactly how I would do it. I'm not an eagle expert but I don't think you can define angles, electronic cads are quite primitive.

Comment: The open source Geda package "PCB" can place components or rectangular pads at arbitrary angles, should you ever need to. But I concur that for placing round holes as here, a spreadsheet is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x = r cos(angle), y = r sin(angle).

Now, cos(18) = 0.95.  sin(18) = 0.31 . From that you can calc the positions of the four holes above and below the horizontal midline. Proceed similarly for the other four holes, using (18+36) degrees.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a workaround, really. _EDIT:_ There may be a ULP script for this, though.